# Groovy: Unable to load class CTAnchor due to missing dependency CTPosH

Tags: java, groovy, apache-poi

I am using Idea , and here is my bulid.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile project(":signer-core")
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.8'
def poi_version = "3.17"
compile "org.apache.poi:poi:${poi_version}"
compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:${poi_version}"
compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:${poi_version}"
compile "org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:2.1.0"
testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

When I compile this code in *.groovy which I created :

```
    private  CTAnchor getAnchorWithGraphic(CTDrawing drawing /*inline drawing*/,
                                       String drawingDescr, boolean behind) throws Exception {

    CTGraphicalObject graphicalobject = drawing.getInlineArray(0).graphic
    long width = drawing.getInlineArray(0).getExtent().getCx()
    long height = drawing.getInlineArray(0).getExtent().getCy()

    String anchorXML =
            "<wp:anchor xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" "
    +"simplePos=\"0\" relativeHeight=\"0\" behindDoc=\""+((behind)?1:0)+"\" locked=\"0\" layoutInCell=\"1\""
    +"allowOverlap=\"1\">"
    +"<wp:simplePos x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
    +"<wp:positionH relativeFrom=\"column\"><wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset></wp:positionH>"
    +"<wp:positionV relativeFrom=\"paragraph\"><wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset></wp:positionV>"
    +"<wp:extent cx=\""+width+"\" cy=\""+height+"\"/>"
    +"<wp:effectExtent l=\"0\" t=\"0\" r=\"0\" b=\"0\"/><wp:wrapNone/>"
    +"<wp:docPr id=\"1\" name=\"Drawing 0\" descr=\""+drawingDescr+"\"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>"
    +"</wp:anchor>"

    drawing = CTDrawing.Factory.parse(anchorXML)
    CTAnchor anchor = drawing.getAnchorArray(0)

    anchor.setGraphic(graphicalobject)
    return anchor
}
```

It got some errors:

> Error:Groovyc: While compiling signer-office_main: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTAnchor due to missing dependency org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/wordprocessingDrawing/CTPosH

But the code can works in *.java which I created.
And I go into the **CTAnchor.class** to check the **CTPosH** , it really can't not find declaration to go to . But this is the latest **apache poi** version .

[image]

Comment: Try following the advice in the [Apache POI FAQ on this topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)?